# List to a nested dictionary in fastest time possible

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Given a list "a":

```
a = ['Empire:FourKingdoms:', 'US', 'FR', 'DE', 'GB', '208', '96', '42', '149']
```

How would one go about getting the below result, in the fastest run time possible?

```
dict = {'Empire:FourKingdoms:':{'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
```

So end result should be nested dictionary. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a `{` with no matching `}` in your code.

Comment: Sorry mate, it's been fixed, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options (including solutions from other answers):

```
def func_1(d):
    pairs = len(a) // 2
    return {
        d[0]: dict(zip(d[1:1+pairs], d[1+pairs:])),
    }

def func_2(d):
    pairs = len(a) // 2
    return {
        d[0]: {
            k: v
            for k, v in zip(d[1:1+pairs], d[1+pairs:])},
    }

def func_3(d):
    pairs = len(a) // 2
    k_start = 1
    v_start = 1 + pairs
    return {
        d[0]: {
            d[k_start + i]: d[v_start + i]
            for i in range(pairs)},
    }
```

And here are the comparissons:

```
import timeit
a = ['Empire:FourKingdoms:', 'US', 'FR', 'DE', 'GB', '208', '96', '42', '149']

for f in [func_1, func_2, func_3]:
    print(f.__name__)
    print(f(a))
    print(timeit.timeit('f(a)', 'from __main__ import {} as f, a'.format(f.__name__)))
```

The results show that so far `func_2` is faster (using `Python 3.6` on `Ubuntu 18.04`):

```
func_1
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
0.8909805490002327
func_2
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
0.7513965629996164
func_3
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
0.832272507000198
```

Comment: This looks like the most complete answer to me and the most fulfilling. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
pairs = len(a) // 2
result = {a[0]: dict(zip(a[1:1+pairs], a[1+pairs:]))}
```

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738893/9225671) with some time comparissons. Got any other suggestions?